# codeigniter: alteration of PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, insert

i am sending $_POST['checkbox_name'] to function insert_to_table.

```
function insert_to_table($valid_array)
    {
        $data_array = array();

        $this->load->model('get_data_model');
        $updated_max_brand_id = $this->get_data_model->get_max_brand_id();

        foreach ($valid_array as $key => $value) {
            $data_array['bdc_brand_id'] = $updated_max_brand_id;
            $data_array['bdc_cat_id'] = $value;
        }

        $this->db->insert('mart_brand_dealing_cat',$data_array);
    }
```

the final mysql query should run as below

```
INSERT INTO `mart_brand_dealing_cat` (`bdc_brand_id`, `bdc_cat_id`) VALUES (11,43),(11,42);
```

11 - updated_max_brand_id;
42,43 are coming from already existed array $valid_array.

I am trying to insert multiple values at a time.How can i do it. i may wrong please guide and help me.

Comment: `$data_array['bdc_cat_id'] = $valid_array` should perhaps be `$data_array['bdc_cat_id'] = $value`, what $valid_array look like?

Comment: you are right @LawrenceCherone edited wuestion. i was trying and just pasted same code here and forgot to change. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your probably looking for something like [`$this->db->insert_batch();`](https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert_batch)

**So for example:**

```
<?php 
function insert_to_table($valid_array)
{
    $this->load->model('get_data_model');
    $brand_id = $this->get_data_model->get_max_brand_id();

    $insert = array();
    foreach ($valid_array as $key => $cat_id) {
        $insert[] = array(
            'bdc_brand_id' => $brand_id,
            'bdc_cat_id' => $cat_id,
        );
    }

    if (!empty($insert)) {
        return $this->db->insert_batch('mart_brand_dealing_cat', $insert); 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```